# How to include/add .css file using c# in asp.net webpage based on query string or CultureUI

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a multilingual website and need to include CSS file based on either Query String or CultureInfo.

How can a include/add file using c# code i need to write this code in master page.

If language is English then i need to add english.css if language is Arabic then i need to add arabic.css

```
<link href="~/Styles/english.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am not able to get much help from net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline C# code in your aspx files by using <% %> code segments.
in this case you just put a simple check as follow :

```
<% if (Request.QueryString["lang"] == "en") { %>
  <link href="~/Styles/english.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } else { %>
  <link href="~/Styles/otherlang.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks let me try, as i have to check if this code runs before page init as i detect client culture and set the session variable accordingly of query string is empty or not passed. Seems to me it will work